# How to use friend keyword for template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, friend

lets say that I have 2 template classes, A and B. If I want to make B a friend of A, what would I say ?

```
class<template T>
class A
{
public:
friend class B<T>; // ???


};

class<template T>
class B
{

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a symbol, it must be declared or defined, this is the same in template. You need to forward declare template `B`. Also your syntax(`class<template T>`) to declare template class is not valid, it should be `template <class T>`.

This should work:

```
template <typename T>  // typename can be replaced with class 
class B;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
friend class B<T>;  
};

template <typename T>
class B
{

};
```